# The stalk as a colimit

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

From [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf):

> [image]

The notion of colimit is defined for diagrams $D:I\to\textbf{Set}$. The colimit of $D:I\to\textbf{Set}$ is the limit of $D^{op}:I^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}^{op}$. What exactly is the diagram $D:I\to\textbf{Set}$ in 2.2.5? Well, I guess $I$ is given (it's the category whose objects are all open sets containing $p$), and I thought $D$ acts on objects by sending $U$ to $\mathscr F(U)$. But $\mathscr F$ is a contravariant functor, so the $D$ that I defined should be a functor with domain $I^{op}$. How to sort out this mess?

Now, to see that this definition of stalk is equivalent to the non-categorical one, I guess one needs to explicitly describe the colimit. The (vertex of the) colimit (cocone) in this case is $\sum_I \mathscr F (U)$ modulo the equivalence relation generated by something like $\{(f,res_{V,U}(f)): f\in \mathscr F (V), U\subset V\text{ in } I \}$. How is this the same as the set of equivalence classes of pairs of the form $(g,U)$? There is a "type" mismatch.

Comment: What do you mean by a "type" mismatch?  In both cases you are taking a quotient of the disjoint union of the sets $\mathscr{F}(U)$; how is that a mismatch?

Comment: @EricWofsey Isnt in the non-categorical definition the quotient taken over the set of pairs $\{(f, U): ... \}$? I don't see how this set is equal to the disjoint union of $\mathscr F(U)$s.

Comment: What do you think the disjoint union is if not the set of such pairs?

Comment: "How to sort out this mess?" Easy: Take $I$ to be the category whose objects are all open sets containing $p$, and for each pair of objects $U_1$ and $U_2$, there exists precisely one morphism $U_1 \to U_2$ when $U_2 \subseteq U_1$. Then we have a (covariant) functor $I \to \textsf{Set}$ sending $U$ to $\mathscr F(U)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the partial order $\mathcal{O}_X^{op}$, expressed as a category.

That is, $U \to V$ is the set $\{0 \mid V \subseteq U\}$. There is exactly 1 arrow $U \to V$ if and only if $V \subseteq U$, and there is no arrow $U \to V$ otherwise.

Now $\mathscr{F}$ is a functor $\mathcal{O}_X^{op} \to Sets$.

Consider the full subcategory $Neigh_p$ of $\mathcal{O}_X^{op}$, which contains only those open sets that are neighbourhoods of the point $p \in X$. Let $i : Neigh_p \to \mathcal{O}_X^{op}$ be the fully faithful inclusion functor.

Then the colimit is taken over the diagram $\mathscr{F} \circ i : Neigh_p \to Sets$.

To show that this definition is equivalent to the non-categorical one, you need to prove the universal property of the colimit for the non-categorical definition.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by $\{0:V\subseteq U\}$, but the rest is clear.

Comment: @user634426 The "0" part isn't important. In fact, fix a one-element set $1 = \{0\}$. Then we can write it as $\{x \in 1 \mid V \subseteq U\}$. The point here is that there is at most one arrow $U \to V$, and there is one arrow if and only if $V \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to reverse the ordering. In the definition of direct limit, you have morphisms $A_i \rightarrow A_j$ for $i < j$, that is: from the small element to the big element. In this case, you have a restriction morphism $F(U) \rightarrow F(V)$ if $V \subseteq U$, that is : from the big set to the small set.

Therefore, define the partial order on open sets of $X$ as $U < V$ iff $V \subseteq U$.